# Remover usuário sem deletar do banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, criei duas classes dentro do meu Controller, onde eu consigo retirar um usuário de uma pagina e enviar para outra.
Como se estivesse excluindo porém não apagando do banco de dados.

Eu criei uma variável no meu banco de dados chamada **Removido** onde acho que ficaria melhor de se trabalhar, quando **Removido** for = 1 ele transfere este usuário para uma outra página, que neste caso seria como se eu estivesse deletando o usuário daquela pagina

segue o código

**Dentro do Controller**

```
public ActionResult ExcluirCadastro(int id = 0)
        {
            if (!Cookies.Exists("hid")) { 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new { area = "Entrar" });
            }

            var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));

            if (id <= 0 || hospitalId <= 0) {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var excluirCadastro = _cadastroService.GetByPatientId(id, hospitalId);

            if (excluirCadastro != null && excluirCadastro.HospitalId == hospitalId)
            {
                return View(excluirCadastro);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeletarPacientes(int cadastroId)
        {
            var cadastro = _cadastroService.GetbyId(cadastroId);
            cadastro.Removido = !cadastro.Removido;
            _cadastroService.Update(cadastro);
            TempData["sucesso"] = "Paciente excluído com sucesso!"; 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Pagina ExcluirCadastro.cshtml**

```
<h3>Você tem certeza que deseja deletar este Paciente?</h3>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            <a style="color: #000000"><b>Nome</b></a>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.inpac)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            <a style="color: #000000"><b>Data Nascimento</b></a>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dtnasc)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            <a style="color: #000000"><b>Código prontuário</b></a>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pront)
        </dd>
    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="cadastroId" value="@Model.CadastroId" />
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Deletar</button> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Voltar à Lista", "Index")
        </div>
    }
```

quando eu clico no botão Deletar, ele fica sempre entrando neste if

```
var excluirCadastro = _cadastroService.GetByPatientId(id, hospitalId);

            if (excluirCadastro != null && excluirCadastro.HospitalId == hospitalId)
            {
                return View(excluirCadastro);
            }
```

tanto quando eu entro na pagina e tanto quando eu clico em deletar, fica sempre entrando neste if, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Queria que quando eu clicasse em deletar ele mandaria este paciente para uma pagina definida por mim e atualizaria a variavel **Removido** para 1.
e a classe que criei **DeletarPacientes** não estou conseguindo entrar nela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não colocou o banco de dados que está usando vou mostrar via linq uma das soluções.

```
// The Three Parts of a LINQ Query:
    //  1. Data source.
    int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    // 2. Query creation.
    // numQuery is an IEnumerable<int>
    var numQuery =
        from num in numbers
        where (num % 2) == 0
        select num;

    // 3. Query execution.
    foreach (int num in numQuery)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,1} ", num);
    }
```

Ao inves de numero coloque a sua classe onde removido != 1
se for via banco de dados SQL seria algo assim
 
 `Select * from cadastros where removido != 1`

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

olá, em minhas aplicações, realizo lambda, é muito simples. se estiveres usando entity framework, faça da seguinte maneira?
atribua um campo para identificar que fora removido. de depois o seguinte:

```
using(dbcontext db = new dbcontext(){
var RegDelete = db.tabela.where(s=> s.id == id).firstordefault();
if(regdelete != null){
    regdelete.removido = true;
}}
 db.savechanges();
```

SE quiser mais tratamento poderás usar um try catch e capturar o possível erro;

Comment: desculpa, sou novo e não sei como por o código de forma formatada